# Is it possible to use WP-CLI in a plugin (or theme)?

Tags: plugin-development, security, wp-cli

Is it possible to use WP-CLI in a plugin (or theme)?

Such as

```
  $ret = \WP_CLI::execute('plugin list');
```

I want to use some subcommands from other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

[WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) is a command line interface to WP. So, it is used in a Unix shell environment. Plugins and themes are written in PHP (which itself also runs in a shell, usually Unix). So, to execute a WP-CLI command in a plugin you would have to pass it from PHP to the Unix shell. That may be done using the PHP function [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

So, the answer to the question 'is it possible?', is YES. However, the answer to the question 'should I be doing this?' is NO WAY. Here are some considerations:

1. WP-CLI may not even be installed on the server the plugin/theme is used on, for instance because it is a Windows based server.
2. Using `shell_exec` from a theme/plugin is a security risk, because of the powerful commands that are possible on the command line. Many providers block PHP from using `shell_exec` and other execution commands.
3. Everything you can do through WP-CLI can be done in WP proper as well. After all, it is a gateway to WP and offers no additional functionality.

Comment: I don't plan to use `exec` or something.

Comment: So, how are you planning to get the shell command out of the PHP environment?